# Implement serialize to skip field key name and new line if other optional field is None

Tags: rust, serde

I have the following structs:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Container {
    field0: Field<f64>,
    field1: Field<f64>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Field<T> {
    val: T,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    doc: Option<String>,
}
```

**For this instance:**

```rust
Container {
    field0: Field { val: 1.5, doc: Some("my documentation!") },
    field1: Field { val: 2.0, doc: None }
}
```

**I want the following YAML output (since `doc` is `None`):**

```yaml
field0:
  val: 1.5
  doc: my documentation!
field1: 2.0
```

Of course, the derived setup results in this:

```yaml
field0:
  val: 1.5
  doc: my documentation!
field1:
  val: 2.0
```

where `val` is serialized on a new line

I tried implementing `Serialize` for `Field` myself, but wasn't quite sure how to get the key name to go away, and how to get the value on the same line as the name

```rust
impl<T> Serialize for Field<T> where T: Serialize {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        if self.doc.is_some() {
            let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("Field", 2)?;
            state.serialize_field("val", &self.val)?;
            state.serialize_field("doc", &self.doc)?;
            state.end()
        } else {
            let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("Field", 1)?;
            state.serialize_field("", &self.val)?;
            state.skip_field("doc")?;
            state.end()
        }
    }
}
```

resulting in the output:

```yaml
field0:
  val: 1.5
  doc: my documentation!
field1:
  '': 2.0
```

How should I go about implementing it? Is there an easier/cleaner way?

[RUST PLAYGROUND LINK](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2298e271556e84d7e5c36cc130450b4c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy fix. If `doc` is `None`, then you don't want to serialize a struct, just serialize the value directly:

```
if self.doc.is_some() {
    let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("Field", 2)?;
    state.serialize_field("val", &self.val)?;
    state.serialize_field("doc", &self.doc)?;
    state.end()
} else {
    self.val.serialize(serializer)
}
```

With your playground code produces:

```
field0:
  val: 1.5
  doc: my documentation!
field1: 2.0
```

Comment: Aha! I knew I was missing something simple! Thanks

Comment: Do you have any advice on setting up deserialization?

Comment: @KyleCarow For deserialization, it's probably easiest to use an enum: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bbf9c9e7662e90c01ddebfb4c8d52f37

Comment: @drewtato Well done! Given other SO posts I had been slowly settling on a very similar enum, but hadn't thought to have it only within the deserializer, nice!